# ¿Cómo ejecutar código C#?

Tags: c#

Me dejaron de tarea este código, pero no se como correrlo, ¿alguna ayuda?.

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
      Console.WriteLine("You entered the following {0} command line arguments:",
         args.Length );
      for (i=0; i < args.Length; i++)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("{0}", args[i]); 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y Cual es es tu pregunta? ¿Es simplemente que no entiendes este código, o hay con es un error, o...???

Comment: Luis por favor danos más detalles de lo que requieres: entender como funciona, no corre, hay errores de sintaxis, etc... Todo el apoyo que nos puedas detallar servirá para brindarte una respuesta de calidad justo como la que buscas.

Comment: Abajo está mi respuesta para OS X, pero además de eso... en el for debería ser var i = 0 en lugar de i = 0. Eso :)

Comment: Si es para Windows (cosa que estaría bien que especificaras), una magnífica herramienta para ejecutar trozos de código fácilmente es [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net).

Comment: [Instalación de herramientas para desarrollo de aplicaciones Windows 10](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Desarrollador-Windows-10/Instalacin-de-herramientas-para-desarrollo-de-aplicaciones-Windows-10) Tal vez puedas resolver tu duda con este video, espero te sea útil.

Comment: Hola @Luisgaytan ¿Cómo es que la respuesta aceptada tiene votos negativos? Habiendo respuestas muy buenas, ¿como es que te ayudó la aceptada que no tiene nada que ver con el tema?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Otra posible solución si solo quieres ver como se comporta la ejecución de ese código es hacerlo en algún sitio donde puedas ejecutar código online.

Existen muchos sitios como:

- [csharppad.com](http://csharppad.com/) (solo c#)
- [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/) (varios lenguajes pero estás limitado a un entry point específico)
- [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) (en este puedes ejecutar código de un montón de lenguajes)
- [dotnetfiddle.net](http://dotnetfiddle.net/) (C#, F# y VB. NET, puedes elegir el compilador)

En todos ellos puedes ejecutar y compartir tu código.

En este caso he elegido el primero porque puedes simular la entrada del programa y de esta manera ves como se comportaría con los argumentos.

[Aquí te dejo tu ejemplo](http://goo.gl/Jka62L)

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Buena idea. No se como no se me ocurrió esto.

Comment: Muy buenos las App online!

Answer (score 20):

Para ejecutar programas [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) no hay como Visual Studio que tiene el soporte total de Microsoft (Aunque también existe [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/)).

Puedes descargar [aquí](https://www.visualstudio.com/post-download-vs?sku=community&clcid=0x409) la versión community que es **gratuita**

Una vez que hayas descargado e instalado Visual Studio, puedes crear un proyecto

```
File -> New -> Project
```

O si lo bajas en español

```
Archivo -> Nuevo -> Proyecto
```

Y escogemos del lado izquierdo la opción `Visual C#` -> `Windows Desktop`  y finalmente `Console Application`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez terminado te creara una estructura de un proyecto básico y un archivo de inicio, como este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podemos borrar el Archivo `Program.cs` para que no te cause ruido y para agregar tu código solo haremos lo siguiente.

En el menú de herramientas seleccionamos `Project` -> `Add Class` (o en español `Proyecto` -> `Agregar clase`)

En el siguiente Popup solo cambiaremos el nombre a `Example.cs` (Aunque C# no tiene limitaciones por nombre de archivo es buena practica que se llame igual que tu clase)

Esto generara este codigo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Example
    {
    }
}
```

Ahora sustituiremos desde class Example por tu código para que quede así

```
public class Example
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            Console.WriteLine("You entered the following {0} command line arguments:", args.Length);
            for (i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", args[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ahora **hay un problema en tu codigo**, no esta declarada la variable `i` lo mas facil que agreguemos un `int` antes en el ciclo `for` para que quede asi

```
for (int i=0; i < args.Length; i++)
```

Para ejecutar el programa puelsaremos el boton `Start` o `Iniciar`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Por ultimo** lo que realiza tu programa es imprimir valores que son pasados por argumentos desde la consola.

Cuando se ejecuta desde Visual Studio solo se mostrara la consola unos segundos, ya que por default no se pasan argumentos en la ejecución y se cierra automáticamente al terminar el programa.

Necesitamos buscar el archivo .exe creado y ejecutarlo desde cmd

Por default va a estar el `mis documentos\visual studio 2015\Projects\<Nombre de tu proyecto>\<Nombre de tu proyecto>\bin\Debug`

Una vez en la carpeta correcta ejecutaremos en el cmd

```
Example.exe argumento1 argumento2 argumentoN
```

Que debe mostrar Algo como

```
Hello, World!
You entered the following 3 command line arguments:
argumento1
argumento2
argumentoN
```

Answer (score 14):

Asumiendo que no tienes el NET framework en el PATH del sistema (lo cual es por defecto), puedes compilar desde la consola de la siguiente manera:

1. Guarda el código en un archivo, supongamos en `c:\prueba\programa.cs`
2. Te posicionas en el directorio de instalación de NET framework donde está el compilador csc.exe (vX.X.XXXXX es la versión que tengas instalada):

   ```
   > cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vX.X.XXXXX
   ```
3. Para compilar:

   ```
   > csc c:\prueba\programa.cs
   ```

   El resultado estará en el directorio actual.
4. Para correr el ejecutable creado:

   ```
   > programa.exe
   ```

Si tienes el NET framework en el PATH, entonces puedes compilar y ejecutar desde cualquier ubicación:

```
> csc c:\prueba\programa.cs
> programa.cs
```

Por cierto, el código tiene un error de sintaxis, el for debería ser:

```
for (int i=0; i < args.Length; i++)
```

Para mas informacion te dejo el siguiente link que discute maneras de compilar tu aplicación en C# con o sin IDE:

[Compilar aplicaciones en Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cyz1h6zd.aspx)

Comment: Esta es una mala suposición. Las herramientas de desarrollo de .NET no se instalan por defecto en el PATH

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Buen punto. Ahora he considerado primero la situación por defecto. Gracias.

Comment: Ahora esta mejor :)

Comment: Faltaría solo como ejecutar el `.exe` generado

Answer (score 3):

En `OSX` puedes instalar `mono`, que es útil a la hora de compilar archivos `c#` y ejecutarlos de forma posterior.

```
# Para instalar mono
$ brew install mono

# Para compilar el archivo y crear el ejecutable
$ mcs archivo.cs

# Para ejecutar el archivo compilado
$ mono archivo.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Para cuestiones de educación puedes utilizar [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx), es gratis y te servirá para todo lo que vayas a trabajar con tecnologías .NET, ahí seleccionas una nueva aplicación de consola y pegas tu código, como ayuda aquí encontrarás más detalles [Cómo crear una aplicación de consola?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/0wc2kk78(v=vs.90).aspx)